# How can I set the environment value which is begin from a single quote in systemd

Tags: systemd, coreos

I've tried to set following in my systemd's service file

```
Environment=SETTINGS=\'{"a"=1}\'
```

But seems that both the single quotes are been removed, so I get {"a"=1} as the value for the environment variable SETTINGS

How I can set that correctly?

Comment: To be clear: Do you actually _want_ the single quotes to be present in the environment value?

Comment: Unfortunately, I currently need to set something like `METEOR_SETTINGS='{"public":{"ga":{"account":"UA-xxxxxx-2"}}}'`

Comment: I think maybe you can do this in an `EnvironmentFile` with appropriate escaping. But you're deep into [undocumented territory](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=) here. Though, for something like this you really ought to be using an `EnvironmentFile` regardless.

Comment: After reflecting on this a while, I think you have actually found a bug in systemd. This smells like a parser running twice on the same input.

Comment: I've summit it to their bug tracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$ cat /run/user/1000/systemd/user/envtest3.service
[Service]
Environment=SETTINGS=\'{"a"=1}\'
Environment=SETTINGS2='{"a"=1}'

Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/env
```

then

```
$ systemctl --user start envtest3.service
$ journalctl --user -n 2
-- Logs begin at wto 2014-05-27 15:33:38 EDT, end at sob 2014-10-04 11:44:13 EDT. --
paź 04 11:44:13 fedora21 env[27607]: SETTINGS='{"a"=1}'
paź 04 11:44:13 fedora21 env[27607]: SETTINGS2='{"a"=1}'
```

As you can see, the variables get set properly.

You can also use those variables in the unit itself:

```
...
ExecStart=/bin/echo ${SETTINGS} ${SETTINGS2}
ExecStart=/bin/echo $SETTINGS $SETTINGS2
```

and there's surprising thing here:

```
paź 04 14:27:50 fedora21-amd64 echo[30304]: '{"a"=1}' '{"a"=1}'
paź 04 14:27:50 fedora21-amd64 echo[30306]: {"a"=1} {"a"=1}
```

The expansion with braces does not strip the quotes, but the other one does. I'm not sure if this is a bug, or not. The manpage says "split at whitespace".

Edit: I'm runninng latest git (v216-456-gba58907547).